# How to save a copy of a folder automatically from sharePoint on a weekly basis?

Tags: windows, network-shares, sharepoint

I need to save a copy of a particular folder present in SharePoint on a weekly basis because the same document is edited and used as new for the next week.

As this is done manually, many times fail to do.

I would be grateful, if someone can suggest the best practices to automate it ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to create a .BAT file that would map the Folder to a network drive and then copy it to a location on your computer.  An example script would be:

```
net use x: /delete
net use x: "https://path/to/your/document/library"
RoboCopy /mir x:\ c:\BackUp
```

You can then configure Windows Task Scheduler to execute this BAT file on a weekly basis as you indicated that you desire to do.

Obviously you will need to modify the BAT file to suite your needs.

You can execute the BAT file independently of the task scheduler as well to ensure that you are getting the results that you want before tying it to a Windows Task.